# How to decompose BeautifulSoup Tag copy in source HTML code?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an element extractor, and have an issue with removing it in source BeautifulSoup object

Example:

```
def extract_element(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup) -> bs4.Tag:
    tag = soup.select('my-css-selector-or-something-else')
    return copy.copy(tag)


## main body code
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('my-html-code', 'my-parser')
ignore_tag = extract_element(soup)
if ignore_tag is not None:
     ignore_tag.decompose()   # doesn't modifies soup object
```

`extract_element` contains complicated logic and uses for element extraction, so it shouldn't modify existing `soup` object in function body

Comment: `soup.select(...)` returns a list of tags and not a single tag. So, your function `extract_element` returns a list. You have to iterate over this list and then decompose the tags. If you want only a single tag (the first match), use `select_one` instead of `select`.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar oh, thats my mistake in example, sorry. I've wrote it just to show that I'm breaks dependencies with parent `soup` object  and use it as independent one

Problem is how to delete from parent BeautifulSoup object `soup` some independent `bs4.Tag` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I found one solution for this problem

```
def extract_element(soup: bs4.BeautifulSoup) -> bs4.Tag:
tag = soup.select('my-css-selector-or-something-else')
return copy.copy(tag)


## main body code
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('my-html-code', 'my-parser')
ignore_tag = extract_element(soup)
if ignore_tag is not None:
     soup.find(attrs=ignore_tag.attrs).decompose()
```

It will delete **first specific element** on page, but in some cases there can be issues.
It solved problem for me, I hope it will inspire you